# how to compare 2 XML using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare 2 XML files.

My xml1 is:

```
<ROOT><NODE><BOOK><ID>1234</ID><NAME isbn="dafdfad">Numbers: Language of Science</NAME><AUTHOR>Tobias Dantzig</AUTHOR></BOOK></NODE></ROOT>
```

I have another XML from database which is

```
<Book xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><Id>12345</Id><Name isbn="31231223">Numbers: Language of Science</Name><Author>Tobias Dantzig</Author></Book>
```

I want to compare the "BOOK" node from XML1 and "Book" node from db XML

1. I have a Name-space in the XML which is obtained from database
2. The node names are in mixed cases

I want to compare these 2 XML files node by node for Text and attributes value

I am using C# and wanted to know if this is possible using LINQ

Any help would be really appreciated

P.S. I searched for similar posts but couldn't find what i am exactly looking for.

Thanks a lot in advance

Cheers,
Karthik

Comment: Assume you compare them what's the result of comparison?

Comment: what i want to have is, if the Value's are different then i want to store them in an attribute in xml1 . Ex: if ID value is different then after comparison i want to store like <ID isChanged="true">1234</ID>

Comment: +1, the *general* problem is interesting is an interesting problem.  I don't think it is a good application for LINQ, though.  The tools that come to mind are `IEnumerable<T>.Except`, which will only be useful to output nodes that are missing in one/the other collection.  You'll also have to write a custom comparison (not sure if `Except` supports that), and a tree-flattener.  The results won't be in a tree, so you may have to do some dictionary magic to get your diff results back in a tree.  Do you care if you have a general solution?

Answer (score 5):

In xml, case and namespace are fundamentally important, and whitespace and attribute-order *aren't* (making direct string compares incorrect).

So IMO you should parse it; perhaps with `XmlSerializer`, but (as you note) both are trivially parsed with LINQ-to-XML:

```
string xml1 = @"<ROOT><NODE><BOOK><ID>1234</ID><NAME isbn=""dafdfad"">Numbers: Language of Science</NAME><AUTHOR>Tobias Dantzig</AUTHOR></BOOK></NODE></ROOT>";

var book1 = (from book in XElement.Parse(xml1).Elements("NODE").Elements("BOOK")
            let nameEl = book.Element("NAME")
            select new
            {
                Id = (int)book.Element("ID"),
                Name = nameEl.Value,
                Isbn = (string)nameEl.Attribute("isbn"),
                Author = (string)book.Element("AUTHOR")
            }).Single();

string xml2 = @"<Book xmlns:rdf=""http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#""><Id>12345</Id><Name isbn=""31231223"">Numbers: Language of Science</Name><Author>Tobias Dantzig</Author></Book>";
var el = XElement.Parse(xml2);
var book2 = new
{
    Id = (int)el.Element("Id"),
    Name = el.Element("Name").Value,
    Isbn = el.Element("Name").Attribute("isbn"),
    Author = el.Element("Author")
};
```

Then it is just a case of comparing the values.

---

An alternative is to use something like xslt to pre-process one of the files to match the expected layout of the other, so you can share parsing code. It depends whether you are already familiar with xslt, I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this. Since my original XML has more number of nodes, and also I don't want to hardcore the node names, i was wondering if there could be something easy

Comment: @Karthik xslt might be useful for trnaslating element names to upper-case, but the requirement is a bit... unusual.

Comment: Yeah true :-) My worry is in future, there can be additions to XML Node names and I don't want my code to change for  this. I will check for XSLT as well.

Answer (score -2):

can be done quite easily  using [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) or even simple [Xml DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87.aspx).
though i would bravely do it with [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx).
one regex to find all the books, and a couple or so do dismantle each record.